# Как такое сделать с помощью блокировщика рекламы или другого расширения для Chrome?

Tags: javascript, расширения, реклама

Есть сайт для создания зеркальных ссылок - https://multiup.org/

Если загрузить файл, перейти по сгенерированной ссылке и там нажать на кнопку Download, то откроется страница с ссылками на ресурсы, откуда можно скачать этот файл.

Вот пример такого файла - https://multiup.org/download/78eb1a42294c2b3e2e94d05a4605ae6f/PhysXPainter_v2.0_iND.rar

Проблема в том, что когда мы под иконкой ресурса (например Mega.co.nz), с которого хотим скачать, **первый раз** нажимаем на кнопку "Download", то нас перекидывает на левый рекламный сайт. Если вернуться обратно, нажав в браузере кнопку назад и снова нажать на эту кнопку, то уже перекидывает на нужный нам сайт с которого можно скачать файл.

Я посмотрел код страницы в DevTools, вот что увидел:
[image]

Поэкспериментировав я установил, что оптимальным вариантом будет, если button из form переместить на уровень выше сделав его ребенком тега footer. Удалить тег form. Тег buton заменить на тег "a" и в нем атрибут link заменить на href.
Получится вот так:

[image]

Я почитал немного про создание собственных фильтров и понял, что эти фильтры могут только блокировать определенные куски страницы, мне же надо проделать разные манипуляции с кусками страницы.

Можно ли описанное выше изменение сделать с помощью фильтров или еще каких-нибудь функций блокировщиков рекламы? (Я использую uBlock Origin, так что желательно с помощью его функций) Если да то как? Что гуглить, в каком направление "капать"?

Я могу написать функцию на javascript, которая смогла сделать описанные выше манипуляции, но как мне сделать так, чтобы она запускалась именно на нужном мне сайте?

Может есть более оптимальные пути сделать так, чтобы на сайте multiup не перекидывало на рекламные ресурсы?

Comment: `запускалась именно на нужном мне сайте` - в файле `manifest` своего расширения добавьте `"permissions": ["https://WEBSITE_WHAT_I_NEED.com/"]`. Теперь у расширения есть доступ к документу сайта, и он сможет его изменять

Answer (score 0):

#### Вариант 1.

Найдите скрипт который отвечает за открытия рекламы и заблокируйте его

#### Вариант 2.

Напишите Юзерскрипт для Tampermonkey, который будет удалять всё чтотне нужно и оставлять только ссылки